# How to make a dynamic app icon in android/ios which changes in the background automatically?

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, react-native

If anyone knows the realme mobile in that the clock app icon is dynamic means that it changes according to current time how to achieve this in android or in java or flutter or react native

[image]

I have search but found nothing.

Comment: "I haven't tried anything." Even though I applaud your honesty, that's not an approach that will convince many to help you out.

Comment: Did you really search in Google? Just putting your title lead me to many links for me.

Comment: I have found changing it programatically but i want to change in background like this clock app it changes the position of minute app and hour hand as the time changes

Comment: You can't do this on iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

practically thats not possible. on iOS not at all, on Android there is a way (search for `<activity-alias` tag and switching app launcher icon), but isn't desired to such often changes, thus probably not efficient, not "device-friendly". There is a chance that Android itself or fork of it from some manufacturer may limit your app in such possibility recognizing this behavior as impersonation

note that app which can change icon oftenly is always a system app - clock, calendar, etc. Such apps have special privileges added to them by manufacturers (Apple, Samsung, Xiaomi etc.), not possible to be granted for common non-system apps. On Android you can install a different "desktop app", called App launcher, and I bet these "live icons" aren't working on some of them, maybe all

For Android you may consider [App widget](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/overview) for oftenly-changed data presentation, but even this feature have some limitation: "default" smallest refreshing interval is [15 minutes](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/advanced#periodic), performance reasons ofc. but in here you may ommit this limitation with own refreshing mechanism based e.g. on `AlarmManager` and/or `WorkManager`. Widgets were introduced also for iOS, so it looks thats a best way for you